# Sharepoint 2013 People picker- shows duplicate records. How to ignore AD user records

Tags: people-picker, domain

I have a list of migrated users from Domain "OLD" to Domain "NEW". Under User profiles, I see only Domain "New"  users.

People picker on my SharePoint 2013 site (https) shows results from Domain "NEW" as well as Domain "OLD". It should not show Domain "OLD" records.

On the same SharePoint Server I have "My Sites", people picker on my sites shows results from  Domain "New" only. Which is correct and expected.

When I try to run stsadm.exe commands on any PeoplePicker property (for example :  `peoplepicker-nowindowsaccountsfornonwindowsauthenticationmode` ), the command errors out ("The  System cannot find the path specified), if I specify  following URL with "HTTPS". However if I provide "HTTP" instead of HTTPS, the command works absolutely fine.

Any advice on :
1). Why is stsadm command not working with Https URL? URL with https is correct for sure,it's a live site.
2). How can I restrict Domain "Old" users from people picker. Right now I am not able to compare the properties of above sites using stsadm command as the command does not execute for HTTPS URL.

Comment: Concerning your second question. I think you can use the Powershell command Move-SPUser to 'migrate' (old) users to their new users in SharePoint 2013 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Pls consider exploring on the trust related concepts. Is there any trust b/w two domains or AD forests ?